# Linker can't find shared library compiled by g++

Tags: g++, ld

I have the following files:

funcs.hpp:

```
#include "iostream"

void func(void);
```

funcs.cpp:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "funcs.hpp"

void func(void)
{
        std::cout<< "Running func" << std::endl;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "iostream"

extern void func(void);


int main(void)
{
        std::cout<< "call func" << std::endl;
        func();
        return 1;
}
```

I compiled funcs.cpp into shared library via command:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared funcs.cpp -o libfuncs.so
```

Then I call

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -llibfuncs -o main.o
```

To link the shared library to main and compile but I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibfuncs: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I follow the examples I saw on line exactly, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: -llibfuncs is not what you want. Pay attention to what -l flag really does. Read the docs.

Comment: Ah so it looks like it's supposed to be -lfuncs instead. This https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html doesn't cover that which is odd.

Comment: I guess they assume you know how to *use* libraries before you attempt to *creare* one. But sure enough they could have mention this.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was gcc assumes lib will be added to the library name, you need to remove the lib portion, the correct command is:

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -lfuncs -o main.o
```

I think this is poorly documented.

Comment: Fot reliable information about GCC commandline options it's best to consult [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/#toc-GCC-Command-Options). The`-l` option is covered in section [3.15 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html)